# How to sort the gridview in asp.net when you have to float number like value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have SQL database having column name "No" having varchar(50) data type and value is like 1.1, 1.2, 1.12,1.13, 1.21.... and i'm displaying data in gridview with sorting order is "ASC". Now the problem is i want to sort the data like

1.1,
1.2,
1.12,
1.13,
1.21,...

but the result i got is

1.1,
1.12,
1.13,
1.2,
1.21,...

Here is my code

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))


{
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = cnn;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                        dv.Sort = "No ASC";

                        GridView4.DataSource = dv;
                        GridView4.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"i want to sort the data like 1.1, 1.2, 1.12, 1.13, 1.21"_ What's the logic to the ordering you want to achieve? Why does 1.12 come after 1.2?

Comment: @Diado, this is my agenda no which have order 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11, 1.12 and what to sort by this.

Comment: I would suggest to split by a dot and the sort first by the first number and then by the second. And don't forget to convert to integer to get the correct sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to convert every number to string and after that split them with '.' ->
   *var result = number.Split('.');*
2. Take the Convert.ToInt32(result[1]), so for example for number 1.12 you will take only 12 and put it in some new array.

*For your example 1.1, 1.2, 1.12,1.13, 1.21 you will have new array with 1,2,12,13,21.*

3. Sort that array and after that add prefix on every member of it with "1."
4. After that part, you'll have array like: {1.1,1.2,1.12,1.13,1.21,...}

This is my logic with numbers beginning with 1, but if you have numbers beginning with some other number you can do the same logic for every number and after each obtained and sorted array, insert into one special array: 
Example: {1.1,1.2,1.12,...} {2.1,2.2,2.12,...} -> {1.1,1.2,1.12,...,2.1,2.2,2.12,...}

I hope that my logic will help you and that you will solve this problem.

Comment: Well, Thank you for your replay. This logic will surely work but I have found the the solution by putting "0" after ".". That is have given agenda number like..1.01, 1.02, 1.03.....and this is working.